# Qual melhor forma de se fazer uma tabela de espalhamento

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho de implementar uma tabela hash, também conhecida como tabela de espalhamento, no entanto minha inexperiência com essa estrutura de dados pode fazer com que ocorra muitas colisões na minha implementação. Gostaria de saber quais praticas devo abordar e como saber se minha tabela está bem espalhada.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse artigo: https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-estrutura-dados/tabelas-de-espalhamento/#9-1-introducao. Se a dúvida persistir, seria uma boa ideia especificar mais sua pergunta, como por exemplo adicionando mais detalhes sobre seu caso. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma tabela de espelhamento usa alguns *slots* para armazenar objetos de acordo com o *hash*, não o *hash* em si.

Colisões são esperadas, já que vários *hashes* podem ser armazenados no mesmo *slot*.

Uma das implementações internas do Java cria um array de *slots* baseado no número de elementos na tabela (mapa, no caso).

Como *hashes* não são nada mais que números, basicamente se faz uma conta e se determina que se o número do *hash* está num determinado intervalo ele vai parar numa posição do vetor.

Por exemplo, imagine que no seu sistema *hashes* podem assumir valores de `1..100`. Você pode criar uma tabela com `10` posições de forma que se o *hash* de um elemento pertence ao conjunto `[1..10]`, ele será colocado na primeira posição da tabela. E assim por diante.

Cada posição da tabela é na verdade uma lista de elementos. Quando há colisão na hora de incluir, você simplesmente adiciona o novo elemento na lista.

O problema é que na hora de recuperar, além de encontrar a posição na tabela, você tem que percorrer essa lista verificando se o elemento a ser retirado da tabela está naquela lista.

A implicação disso é que os algoritmos mais eficientes de *hashing* são aqueles que geram valores mais uniformemente distribuídos.

Além disso, uma implementação mais avançada pode verificar se existem muitos conflitos e aumentar dinamicamente a quantidade de posições na tabela de espelhamento, de forma a diminuir o número de colisões.